# Bxslider does not transition automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using the bxslider plugin and everything seems to work fine except that it doesnt ever slide automatically. I have to press prev/next.

Here are my jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            controls: true,
            autoControls: true,
            auto: true,
            randomStart: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

The only way for it to slide is for me to press "play". i just want it to do that automatically.

Comment: well if lib has bug, you can just trigger click on Play with js

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with the following code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
            slider.startAuto();
    });
```